# How to create an observable of the unread messages from the observable of all the messages

Tags: angular, reactive-programming, rxjs, rxjs5

There is a websocket echo service, which send and receive messages:

```
@Injectable()
export class NotificationsService {
  private ws = new $WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org');

  wsSendMessage(message: string = `Message ${Math.random()}`): void {
    this.ws.send(message);
  }

  wsGetMessages(): Observable<string> {
    return Observable.from(this.ws.getDataStream())
      .map((res: any) => res.data);
  }
}
```

Notifications component subscribes to this observable and shows all the messages in the notification dropdown panel:

```
  getMessages(): void {
    this.notificationsService.wsGetMessages().subscribe(
        (message: string) => {
          this.messages.unshift(message);
        },
        (err: any) => console.log(err)
    );    
  }
```

I need to show the number of unread messages in the navbar component and set it to 0, when the notification dropdown panel is opened. And I have no ideas about how to do it, so I need your help...

**P.S.**

Now websocket echo service is:

```
@Injectable()
export class NotificationsService {
  private ws = new $WebSocket('wss://echo.websocket.org');

  wsSendMessage(message: string = `Message ${Math.random()}`): void {
    this.ws.send(message);
  }

  wsGetMessages(): Observable<Object> {
    return Observable.from(this.ws.getDataStream())
      .map((res: any) => res.data);
  }

  messagesReadStream(msgArray: Object[]): Observable<Object> {
    return Observable.from(msgArray);
  }
}
```

and notifications component is:

```
export class Notifications implements OnInit {
  messagesAll:string[] = [];
  messagesRead:string[] = [];
  newMessagesNumber:number = 0;

  constructor(private notificationsService: NotificationsService) {
  }

  addMessage(): void {
    this.notificationsService.wsSendMessage();
  }

  getMessages(): void {
    this.notificationsService.wsGetMessages()
      .subscribe(
        (message: any) => this.messagesAll.unshift(message),
        (err: any) => console.error(err)
      );
  }

  readMessages(): void {
    this.messagesRead = this.messagesAll.slice();

    this.notificationsService.messagesReadStream(this.messagesRead)
      .switchMap(() => 
        this.notificationsService
          .wsGetMessages()
          .scan((unread, _) => unread + 1, 0)    
          .startWith(0))
      .subscribe(
        (count: number) => this.newMessagesNumber = count,
        (err: any) => console.error(err)
      );    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMessages();
  }  
}
```

with template:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-outline btn-sm" (click) = "addMessage()">
  Add message
</button>  

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary-outline btn-sm" (click) = "readMessages()">
  Read messages
</button>  

<div style="margin-top: 1rem">
  <span class="circle bg-warning fw-bold">
      {{newMessagesNumber}}
  </span>  
</div>
```

And now if I click `button 'Add message'` my counter doesn't change value from `0`. And only if I click `button 'Add message'`, then click `button 'Read messages'` and then click `button 'Add message'` again counter starts working good. Can you explain, what the problem is?

Comment: Which part isn't working?

Comment: wsGetMessages() returns an Observable with all the messages from the websocket server. And I need to show the number of unread messages. It's the same before I open the notification panel. But after it has to count only new messages. I think it would be another observable with all the readed messages. But how to create it???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need more than one `Observable`. One to contain the count and one to signal when messages have been read. The former will use the `wsGetMessage` stream while the latter will have to be connected to an Observable that fires whenever the notification panel is opened.

```
const panelOpened: Observable<any> = //..Need a signalling mechanism for when the messages get read

const unreadCount: Observable<number> = messagesRead.switchMap(() => 
   this.notificationsService
         .wsGetMessages()
         //Just count all of the messages as they come in.
         .scan((unread, _) => unread + 1, 0)
         //Make sure it always gets reset to zero
         .startWith(0));

//Subscribe to updates on count changes.
unreadCount.subscribe(count => this.unreadMessageCount = count);
```

Comment: I've updated my code in question due to your recommendations, but still have one problem. Can you help with it?